# disable javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm have a function which shows a div when the user types something but it interferes with a page where I have an input. I would like to disable the script when the part of the page with the div that holds the inputs is visible so that when the user is typing in the input the .editPro doesn't show().

HTML

```
<div class="green" style="width:100%;height:100%;position: fixed;display:none;background:green;">
    <input type='text' />
</div>
<div class="editPro" style="width:100%;height:100%;position: fixed;display:none;background:red;"></div>
<div id='edit'>edit</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
 $('#edit').click(function (event) {
     $(".green").show("slow");

 });

 $(document).keypress(function (event) {
     $(".editPro").show("slow");
 });
```

here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Un8yv/) to illustrate the problem

Comment: have youtried disconnecting the event handler?

Comment: I have no idea what that is.

Comment: You fiddle is empty :(

Comment: Try now.. I'm not very good with jsfiddle either :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check the target node. If it is not an input, then execute your script

```
 $(document).keypress(function (event) {
    if(event.target.nodeName !== "INPUT"){
       $(".editPro").show("slow");
    }
 });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Un8yv/3/)

Comment: This works great for the inputs but is there a way to disable everything if .green is visible? I tried changing your code to `event.target.hasClass !== 'green'`. I didn't consider the fact that the person my not have selected the input and just type something (accidentally).

Comment: as in, if the user has not selected the input to not show the red

Comment: you could try $(event.target).hasClass('green')

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly, but maybe this is what you are looking for (it prevents the red div from appearing when you type inside a `<input/>`):

```
$('input').keypress(function (event) {
     event.stopPropagation();
 });
```

[**http://jsfiddle.net/Un8yv/1/**](http://jsfiddle.net/Un8yv/1/)

Comment: Thanks, this works great too. Is there a way to prevent the red div from appearing if the green is visible (not only when typing into the input)?

Comment: Yes, it's possible: [`if($('.green').is(':visible'))return;`](http://jsfiddle.net/Un8yv/15/)

Answer (score 0):

I have done some changes in your code hope this helps

try this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/venkat_asman/Un8yv/2/)

```
http://jsfiddle.net/venkat_asman/Un8yv/2/
<div class="green" style="width:100%;height:100%;position: fixed;display:none;background:green;z-index:100;">
</div>
<div class="editPro" style="width:100%;height:100%;position:fixed;display:none;background:red;z-index:100;"></div>
<div id='edit'>edit</div>
  <input style="z-index:1000;display:none;position:fixed;" type='text' />
```

and JS is

```
    $('#edit').click(function(event){
    $(".green").show("slow");
    $("input").show();
   $('#edit').hide();

});

 $(document).keypress(function(event){
    $(".editPro").show("slow");
});
```